# Open Excel OLEObject in a new Excel instance

Tags: excel, vba

I just learned to open programmatically embedded OLEObjects by following VBA-Excel code:

```
mySheet.OLEObjects(myName).Verb xlVerbOpen
```

However, if "myName" corresponds to an Excel object, the Excel file is opened in the same Excel instance in which I am running the program. Since at that time there are a couple of forms opened, I would like this object to be opened in a new Excel instance (and not behind the forms, as it is now happening). Is this possible? How could I do it? Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can create new Excel Instance in your code (in the below sample - `xlApp`) and refer to that instance in whatever you do next (however this will work only if OLEObject is created with link):

```
Dim xlApp As New Excel.Application, xlWb As Workbook

Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
xlApp.Visible = True 'Make new instance visible (by default it's not visible)
Set xlWb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(Filename) ' Filename is path to the linked workbook
```

If OLEObject is not linked the only way to open in new Excel instance is to open with the main excel file, which is not what you want:

```
xlApp.Workbooks.Open(workbookpath).Worksheets("mySheet").OLEObjects(myName).Verb xlVerbOpen
```

Comment: Thanks Richard, but I am afraid it did not solve my problem. The oleobject (.xlsx file) I want to open in a new workbook is embedded within the current workbook in which I am running the program (I do not want to open the same workbook again in a new instance). What I need is just to open the oleobject in a new workbook (a non-existing one). In other words, following your code, I would need to replace "Filename" by "oleobject in current workbook", but I do not know the syntax to get it or even if it is possible.

Comment: You are right - the only way to open embedded object in a new instance is to open the entire workbook with macros again (which is not what you want). You can not reference to embedded object without referencing to the main workbook. I would suggest embed the object as link so that you can open embedded object just like regular workbook (I edited my post).

Comment: Thanks Richard. Link will not be useful, since the workbook might change from one computer to another. However I will explore the option of re-opening same workbook.

Comment: Just for your information, I finally succeed opening the embedded Excel file in a new Excel instance by (1) opening a new Excel instance, (2) adding a workbook to the new instance, (3) copying the OLEObject to the new workbook and (4) opening the OLEObject from the new workbook. Regards.

Comment: Congrats @i_caster, I would put your steps with details as an answer it might help somebody else dealing with the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Following Richard's suggestion, see below the code I built to be able to open an embedded excel object through VBA in a new workbook within a new Excel instance:

```
                Dim xlApp As excel.Application
                Dim xlWb  As Workbook
                Dim mySheet As Worksheet
                Dim myName as String

                Set mySheet = Sheets("write sheet name")
                Set myName = Sheets("write object name")

                ThisWorkbook.Sheets(mySheet).OLEObjects(myName).Copy
                Set xlApp = New excel.Application
                xlApp.Visible = True
                Set xlWb = xlApp.Workbooks.Add
                xlWb.Sheets(1).Paste
                xlWb.Sheets(1).OLEObjects(myName).Verb xlVerbOpen
```

Regards